# Hide LINK in user account Prestashop for a specific USer Group ID

Tags: prestashop

Hi guys according with this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DVX08.png)
i want to hide this links tabs for a specific id group user in Prestashop 1.7.6.
is there any way?
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I guess that wrapping the code in `theme/templates/customer/my-account.tpl` within a condition

```
{if $customer.id_default_group != 'limited_group_id_here'}
   // code goes here
{/if}
```

would be enough

Comment: @WytexSystem If the answer helped to you, you may accept and vote it